# Is "с днём рождения, старый пердун" acceptable?

Tags: сленг

I would like to congratulate someone I know well for his 50th birthday.

Would the following be considered good, ok, bad or very bad?

> С днем рождения, старый пердун!

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Difficult to say which one I should consider "the" answer since they all share some truth. To honor that I'll upvote all and mark none as answer.

Comment: "Алкаш" уж лучше тогда. :-O

Comment: Do not say like that if you met a person for the first time; otherwise, you will get punched or slapped on your face:)

Comment: Be careful with this one. You need to know a person very well and have a really close relationship with him to call him "пердун" otherwise your chances of getting a smack in a face are very high. Reminds me of a Grand Torino movie scene where Walt talks to his barber friend https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GtSJOUOEJ8o

Answer (score 12):

Depends on the terms you're on with this person, because this is quite offensive, i mean it could be taken as a friendly banter by a good friend and as an insult by a stranger.

I think it's as strong as its English equivalent "Happy Birthday, old fart!"

Comment: More offensive actually. The English variant isn't polite, but it's still much softer than the Russian one.

Answer (score 9):

**Don't!** You will definitely spoil the celebration. Or at least remind that person of his age. Do you know the meaning of the last word? I bet you don't. Look it up in your dictionary.

We don't capitalize letters in С днём рождения!

Comment: Why so aggressive? So many !!!!!

Comment: Being expressive is not aggressive (a poem, lol, btw.there's only one! )

Comment: Actually using slang expressions is not encouraged for language learners. Imagine a person which hardly speaks English, but attempting to use slang words. Most of the time you'll wonder "maybe he used the wrong word to express something different?".

Answer (score 8):

Depends on the person's sensitivity and sense of humour really. If in doubt, don't.

Anyway, you might find this useful: **старый пердун** has a Soviet-era slang form, **старпёр** (parodying the Communist knack for acronymising everything), which comes across as less risqué and which should be familiar enough to a person of that age.

Answer (score 2):

Using your scale it's "bad". Definitely, it's not that "very bad", but still "bad" enough.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the level of your relationship with the person in question.
Quite acceptable actually between very close friends, in my circle at least.